# Horizontal Scrollable chart has bad performance

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I want to implement a line chart which would be horizontal scrollable. The problem is when using the code below that the performance is pretty bad. Probably because the whole chart gets rendered.

Is there a way to render only the part from the chart which is shown? Or is there a better approach?

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(2000, 200),
        painter: ChartPainter(points),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the problem but had to do it in a different approach. Instead having a wide chart, which has to be rendered also outside of the view, I changed `ChartPainter` to paint only the points which are visible. I added the "scrolling" behavior by listening to a controller and passing the position to the `ChartPainter` which would than use the position to move the points accordantly.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final controller = widget.controller;
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.position.haveDimensions) {
        setState(() {
          offsetX = -controller.position.pixels;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        CustomPaint(
          painter: ChartPainter(points, offsetX),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```